# Swig -> Perl5 : Error compiling simplest SWIG-Module with VC15

Tags: perl, visual-c++, swig, perl-module

I have a quite simple Swig Module for Demo purposes but can't get the wrapper/stub to get compiled.

Swigtest.h:

```
#pragma once
class Swigtest {

public:
    Swigtest() {};
    int func1(int param1);
};
```

Swigtest.cpp

```
#include "Swigtest.h"

int Swigtest::func1(int param1)
{
    return param1 + 1;
}
```

Swigtest.i

```
%module Swigtest

%{
    #include "Swigtest.h"
%}

%include "Swigtest.h"
```

The wrapper ist generated with `swig.exe -c++ -perl5 Swigtest.i` and then the compilation of the wrapper `Swigtest_wrap.cxx` fails with the following first error:

> [path_to_perl_lib]\lib\core\win32.h(371): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'STRLEN'

I'm using VisualStudio 2015 Toolset (acutally running on VS17) with Target Platform Version 8.1 and Swigwin 3.0.12.

Thank's for your help!

Comment: What's the *Perl* package and version you have installed (as there are many) ? Also please post the full error, and if possible the *compile* (and also *link*) command(s).